# "We should fixate a day every week to meet each other." Does this sentence sound natural?

Tags: expressions, verbs

If I want to meet a friend on a weekly basis, how can I express that we need to schedule a day every week to meet on? For instance, every Tuesday. Can I say "let's fixate a day every week to meet on"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly you shouldn't say "fixate".  The word has several meanings, but is [often used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(psychology)) to describe an obsession, or compulsion.

How about "set" instead?

"Let us set a day for weekly meetings"

Answer (score 1):

you can say any of these:

1- lets pick a weekday to meet every week. 
2- lets fix a day to meet every week. 
3- lets pick a day and meet every week 
4- lets pick a day so we can have our sessions every week on that day (if it is a session for teaching or something similar) 

or if you want to be more polite: 
1- we can choose a day and meet every week on that day 
2- would it be possible to choose a day and meet on a weekly basis?

Comment: Thank you, Mey.

Comment: Specifically, note that "fix" and "fixate" are different verbs with different meanings. To "fixate" means to develop an obsessive attachment to someone or something.